# Why does helium-3 stay in the moon and not escape from it?

Tags: planetary-science, moon

So the moon is full of helium-3.

Since it's a gas in the moon's vacuum... Why doesn't it escape?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your claim?

Comment: InquilineKea is not in the habit of putting a lot of effort into questions. Rather, of putting a little effort into lot of questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Moon is not "full" of helium-3. <sup>3</sup>He is at most fifty parts per billion of the lunar regolith<sup>1</sup> and that "high" concentration pertains only to permanently shadowed craters. The Moon is bombarded by a steady stream of helium-3 while sunlit. Some of this incoming helium-3 is temporarily embedded in the lunar regolith. Without this steady supply, the helium-3 content would dissipate at a temperature-dependent rate proportional to the amount of helium-3 in the lunar regolith.

The quantity $q(t)$ of in a cubic meter of lunar regolith is thus dictated by a simple differential equation, $\dot q(t) = \alpha(t) - \beta(T)q(t)$. Time averaging the bombardment and escape rates yields $\dot {\bar q}(t) = \bar{\alpha} - \beta(\bar T)q(t)$. This differential equation yields a steady state value of $\bar q = \bar{\alpha}/\beta(\bar T)$.

<sup>1</sup> Cooks, "<sup>3</sup>He in permanently shadowed lunar polar surfaces", *Icarus*, 206:2 778-779 (2010).